# Graph branch decomposition

Tags: graph

[image]
Hello,

I would like to know about an algorithm to produce a graph decomposition into branches with rank in the following way:

```
Rank | path (or tree branch)
0      1-2
1      2-3-4-5-6
1      2-7
2      7-8
2      7-9
```

The node 1 would be the Root node and the nodes 6, 8 and 9 would be the end nodes.
the rank of a branch should be given by the number of bifurcation nodes up to the root node. Let's assume that the graph has no loops (But I'd like to have no such constraint)

I am electrical engineer, and perhaps this is a very standard problem, but so far I have only found the BFS algorithm to get the paths, and all the cut sets stuff. I also don't know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737690/algorithm-for-generating-a-tree-decomposition) applies.

I hope that my question is clear enough.

PS: should this question be in stack overflow?

Answer (score 2):

From your example, I'm making some assumptions:

- You want to bifurcate whenever a node's degree is > 2
- Your input graph is acyclic

With an augmented BFS this is possible from the root `r`. The following will generate `comp_groups`, which will be a list of components (each of which is a list of its member vertices). The rank of each component will be under the same index in the list `rank`.

```
comp[1..n] = -1           // init all vertices to belong to no components
comp[r] = 0               // r is part of component 0
comp_groups = [[r]]       // a list of lists, with the start of component 0
rank[0] = 0               // component 0 (contains root) has rank 0 
next_comp_id = 1

queue = {r}               // queues for BFS
next_queue = {}

while !queue.empty()
  for v in queue
     for u in neighbors(v)
        if comp[u] == -1                       // test if u is unvisited
          if degree(v) > 2
            comp[u] = next_comp_id             // start a new component
            next_comp_id += 1
            rank[comp[u]] = rank[comp[v]] + 1  // new comp's rank is +1
            comp_groups[comp[u]] += [v]        // add v to the new component
          else
            comp[u] = comp[v]                  // use same component
          comp_group[comp[u]] += [u]           // add u to the component
          next_queue += {u}                    // add u to next frontier
  queue = next_queue                     // move on to next frontier
  next_queue = {}
```

Comment: I though of using some sort of BFS as well, but I didn't know if there was something better. Another thing; Which language is it?

Comment: It is probably also possible with DFS, but BFS will be easier to parallelize if needed.

Not any language in particular, just pseudocode.