# tree-decomposition of a graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I need a start point to implement an algorithm in c to generate a tre-decomposition of a graph in input. What i'm looking for it's an algorithm to do this thing.  i will like to have a pseudocode of the algorithm, i don't care about the programming language and I do not care about complexity

On the web there is a lot of theory but nothing in practice. I've tried to understand how to do an algorithm that can be implemented in c. But it's to hard

i've tried to use the following information:

- [Algorithm for generating a tree decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737690/algorithm-for-generating-a-tree-decomposition)
- https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gerrod_Voigt_final_paper.pdf

and a lot of other info-material. But nothing of this link was useful.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the algorithm to find a node in the tree.

1. Select arbitrary node v
2. Start a DFS from v, and setup subtree sizes
3. Re-position to node v (or start at any arbitrary v that belongs to the tree)
4. Check mathematical condition of centroid for v
5. If condition passed, return current node as centroid
6. Else move to adjacent node with ‘greatest’ subtree size, and back to step 4

And the algorithm for tree decomposition

1. Make the centroid as the root of a new tree (which we will call as the ‘centroid tree’)
2. Recursively decompose the trees in the resulting forest
3. Make the centroids of these trees as children of the centroid which last split them.

And here is an example code.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/centroid-decomposition-of-tree/amp/